# Arial Unicode Ms is not working in xsl-fo for ballot box

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo

Ballot box is not appearing in the printed pdf if the system doesn't contain **Arial unicode MS font**.

```
<fo:inline font-family="arial unicode ms"> ☐ </fo:inline>
```

Is there any other alternate way to show ballot box in xsl-fo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this:

1. find another font that contains this symbol. There are [websites where you can check this](http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/2610-ballot-box), and if all else fails you can use Character Map->Advanced view->Search for: 
   [image]

   2. Place Arial Unicode MS in the directory that contains the XML and stylesheet.
   3. Use SVG to draw a rectangle instead of relying on a font.

Comment: 1) When you find the font, you can just add it to the `font-family` value, e.g.: `font-family="arial unicode ms, Serif"`; 2) If you add a local copy of Arial Unicode MS, you will also need to configure your formatter to use the local font (and also consider the font's licensing).

Comment: A great resource I use all the time is http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2610/fontsupport.htm

Here you can see all the fonts with ballot box. And I would HIGHLY recommend against using Arial Unicode MS. Software that embeds the copyright notice alone for this font (which should be done) would find that the copyright alone for that one character will increase your PDF size considerably.

Comment: <fo:inline>
      <fo:instream-foreign-object>
        <svg:svg width="10" height="10">
          <svg:g style="fill:white; stroke:#000000">
            <svg:rect x="4" y="4" width="5" height="5"/>
          </svg:g>
        </svg:svg>
      </fo:instream-foreign-object>
      <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
    </fo:inline>   this code works for ballot box